# Run action after a build label is set

Tags: teamcity

I have a standard build configuration, ending with a simple ssh copy of the output files to a remote server.

The process wanted is simple:

- The developper pushes the commit to production
- Teamcity builds the product
- The developper downloads the product from the remote server where build results are stored
- The developper tests the product (end-to-end testing, testing setups etc, can't be automated at the moment).
- If the product is okay, label the build that produced this output as the new version (let's say 3.2.1).
- Teamcity applies the label, and moves the files produced by this build to a folder named after the label value (3.2.1 in this example).

Only the last step is missing, because I don't find any ways to connect on the tag action to trigger some sort of build action.

I already tried to link another build configuration to this one, but the issue is that it has to be triggered by the developper for a specific build ID, so the developper tests the output of a given build, if it's okay, he tells teamcity "Okay, release this build as version 3.2.1" and the build artifacts are persisted in a folder named 3_2_1 for instance.